# Is there a real difference between "It was a while before..." "It was after a while that.." ? CAE exam

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, synonyms, semantics, cambridge-exams

I am doing a CAE sample test and I am having a particularly hard time with Part Four of Reading and Use of English. Here, you have to find an alternative way to convey the thing said, using the word given, and I am always close but never close enough, for example (they also provide you with part of the second sentence):

It took me some time to understand fully what happened · the word is: WHILE

It was_______________ understood what had happened

My answer: It was after a WHILE that I fully understood what had happened.

Key answer: It was a while before/until I fully understood what had happened.

is there a different nuance in meaning?

· Another example that stumped me:

There's no point in arguing about this small detail, in my opinion. · the word is: WORTH

This small detail _____________, in my opinion.

my answer:  This small detail is not worth an argument, in my opinion.

key answer: This small detail is not worth arguing about, in my opinion.

now, these are merely sample test for practice only, the thing is with the real exam. I am truly concerned that I get these wrong when I can't really tell the difference between them. thank you in advance for clarifying this.

Comment: The difference is that the key answers are what a native speaker of English would say. Your versions are not grammatically wrong, just unidiomatic.

Comment: thank you for clarifying this to me, it's good to know. Anyways any clue of how I could practice or hone this skill?

Comment: *Before* and *after* have opposite meanings. You can't just replace the one word with the other without changing the meaning of the overall sentence.

Comment: 'After a while, X happened' is just a statement of fact. 'It was/took a while before/until X happened' emphasises the fact that X was delayed (in this case, the speaker was slow to understand what had happened).